# Spin or rotate an image on hover

Tags: css, hover, css-transitions, css-transforms

I want to find out how to make a **spinning or rotating image** when it is hovered. I would like to know how to emulate that functionality with *CSS* on the following code :

```css
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/3DWAbmN.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 214, accepted):

You can use CSS3 transitions with `rotate()` to **spin the image on hover**.

### Rotating image :

```css
img {
  transition: transform .7s ease-in-out;
}
img:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLkKe.jpg" width="100" height="100"/>
```

Here is a fiddle [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/62RJc/2059/)

---

More info and references :

- a guide about CSS transitions on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions)
- a guide about CSS transforms on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)
- browser support table for 2d transforms on [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)
- browser support table for transitions on [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions)

Comment: It works in firefox but not in Chrome. I use a similar code and suddenly it not works in Chrome... Do you know what has happened?

Comment: @ccsakuweb what version of chrome are you using? It works fine for me in latest chrome and according to [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) it should work for chrome back to version 4.

Comment: My version is Versión 40.0.2214.111 m, my problem is that the animation does not work, but in firefox it works.

Comment: @ccsakuweb I don't understand, I have the same version as you on windows 7 and it works fine in the snippet I posted : the image rotates 360 deg on hover.

Comment: I have asked other people with the same version than me and the animation does not work for them either. But a previous version 40.0.2214.96 m, works. I have a friend with the development version and it works for him. So It must be a temporal problem. I hope. Thanks so much for your reply.

Comment: nice to hear that @ccsakuweb

Comment: This is a disgrace. How nobody saw the hover issue with the accepted answer. Border-radius causes that hover issue.

To remove that, you should use a div with back ground image.

Comment: @TimKrul what issue are you talking about?

Comment: Actually in GC, border radius is not obeyed properly. Even howering outside the circle, inside the element box, the transition is triggered. To remove that, you should use a div with back ground image.

Comment: In addition, great css ease tool to bring life to css animations: http://matthewlein.com/ceaser/

Answer (score 7):

It's very simple.

1. You add an image.
2. You create a css property to this image.

   ```css
   img { transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s; }
   ```
3. You add an animation like that:

   ```css
   img:hover
   {
       cursor: default;
       transform: rotate(360deg);
       transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
   }
   ```

Comment: maybe there should be`transition: NUMBER METHOD` instead of `METHOD NUMBER`

Answer (score 4):

if you want to rotate inline elements, you should set the inline element to `inline-block` first.

```css
i {
  display: inline-block;
}

i:hover {
  animation: rotate-btn .5s linear 3;
  -webkit-animation: rotate-btn .5s linear 3;
}

@keyframes rotate-btn {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is my code, this flips on hover and flips back off-hover.

CSS:

```
.flip-container {
  background: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
}

.flip-this {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flip-container:hover .flip-this {
  transition: 0.9s;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="flip-container">
    <div class="flip-this">
        <img width="100" alt="Godot icon" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6a/Godot_icon.svg/512px-Godot_icon.svg.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle this](https://jsfiddle.net/fymaj1h0/1/)

Answer (score 1):

here is the automatic spin and rotating zoom effect using css3

```css
#obj1{
    float:right;
    width: 96px;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 20s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: mymove 20s infinite;
    animation-delay:2s;
    background-image:url("obj1.png");
    transform: scale(1.5);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    -o-transform: scale(1.5);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
    margin-bottom: 70px;
}

#obj2{
    float:right;
    width: 96px;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 20s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: mymove 20s infinite;
    animation-delay:2s;
    background-image:url("obj2.png");
    transform: scale(1.5);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    -o-transform: scale(1.5);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
    margin-bottom: 70px;
}

#obj6{
    float:right;
    width: 96px;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 20s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: mymove 20s infinite;
    animation-delay:2s;
    background-image:url("obj6.png");
    transform: scale(1.5);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    -o-transform: scale(1.5);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
    margin-bottom: 70px;
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes mymove {
    50% {transform: rotate(30deg);
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100px; float:right; ">
    <div id="obj2"></div><br /><br /><br />
    <div id="obj6"></div><br /><br /><br />
    <div id="obj1"></div><br /><br /><br />
</div>
```