# Hi, I can't get the CSS spinning animation to work? Using latest version. Update: running on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows, animation

I can't seem to get the images to spin as I wanted. I believe there's trouble with the image classes but I keep trying and failing to make the animation function.

Here's a part of my code. I only included the code that was relevant to the question:

```html
img: hover {
cursor: default;
transform: rotate(360deg);
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

img: nth-child (1) {
animation-name: spin;
animation-duration: 4s;
animation-iteration-count: 3;
}

@keyframes spin {
from {transform: rotate(0deg); 
}
to {transform: rotate(360deg);
}}

</style>

<body>
<header>My Tutorial 3</header>
<img class = "as" src="as.png" />
<article><header>About this tutorial</header>
In this tutorial I need to make a picture spin for ever...
<img src="a2.png" /></article>
<footer>my footer
<img src="a3.png" /></footer>
<div class="ribbon"><a href="#">My Tutorial 3</a></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What browser are you using? You may need to preface with webkit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23695194/4018167

Comment: Also, pseudo selectors shouldn't have spaces infront of them (`img: hover` should be `img:hover`)

Comment: I'm using Chrome. I've removed the spaces now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your source is rather broken. Try something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
img:hover {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

#spin {
    animation-name: spin;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: 3;
}

@keyframes spin {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg); 
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
</style>
<p><img src="spin.png" id="spin"></p>
<p><img src="spin.jpg"></p>
```

The img with id="spin" gets the anim, whereas the other flips only on hover. Careful with nth-of-type! Except Firefox there's little support for this.

Comment: Hi, would you know what I need to make only 1 of the images spin without using "class" or "id"?

Comment: That's not possible. CSS animations don't work that way.

Answer (score 0):

[Pseudo selectors shouldn't have spaces between the `:` and the name.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes)

Instead of `img: hover`, you should use `img:hover`

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/62RJc/