# How to make image rotate on hover css

Tags: html, css

I want to make my social media icons on the footer of my page rotate on hover. I put a  tag wrapper and individual  tags on each social media icon. On CSS I used '.wrapper' function but when I do '.wrapper:hover' on CSS it wont recognise the ':hover' part.

I don't know what I wrote wrong? Can someone help out.

Much appreciated

HTML

```
        <div class="footer">
        <div id="footer-header">
            <p>Keep Up With Us...</p>
        </div>
        <center><div class="social-wrapper">
            <div id="facebook"><a href="http://www.facebook.com"><img src="Facebook.png" alt="Facebook"></a></div>
            <div id="instagram"><a href="http://www.instagram.com/"><img src="Instagram.png" alt="Instagram"></a></div>
            <div id="twitter"><a href="http://www.twitter.com/"><img src="Twitter.png" alt="Twitter"></a></div>
            <div id="youtube"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/"><img src="Youtube.png" alt="Youtube"></a></div>
        </div></center>
        <div id="tag-branding">
            <img src="tag.png">
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.footer {padding: 376px 0px 0px 0px;}
#footer-header {text-align: center; font-family: 'Raleway'; font-weight: 500; font-size: 29px; line-height: 0; margin: 0;}
#facebook {display: inline; margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;}
#instagram {display: inline; margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;}
#twitter {display: inline; margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;}
#youtube {display: inline; margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;}

#tag-branding {
  padding: 99px 50px 0px 0px;
 }
.social-wrapper {border-radius:50%; -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .8s ease-in-out; -ms-transition: -ms-transform .8s ease-in-out; transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;}
social-wrapper:hover {transform:rotate(360deg); -ms-transform:rotate(360deg); -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);}
```

Also it would be appreciated if you could point out what you changed, if you do, so I could learn for future.

Comment: Hi, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695090/spin-or-rotate-an-image-on-hover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rtate image in css on hover

```css
h1 {
  color: #222;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}

h2 {
  color: #222;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  transition: 0.70s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.70s;
  -moz-transition: 0.70s;
  -ms-transition: 0.70s;
  -o-transition: 0.70s;
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

img:hover {
  transition: 0.70s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.70s;
  -moz-transition: 0.70s;
  -ms-transition: 0.70s;
  -o-transition: 0.70s;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="#333">
  <h1>-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);</h1>
  <h2>Hover to see the effect</h2>
  <img src="http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/lion-wide.jpg">
  <h2>To get it so it works in all web broswers:</h2>
  <h2>Mozilla firefox: -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    <br>
  Opera: -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    <br>
 Internet Explorer: -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    <br>
    CSS3: transform: rotate(180deg);</h2>
  <br>
<h2>The animation:</h2>
<h2>CSS3: transition: 0.70s;
  <br>
  Chrome/Safari: -webkit-transition: 0.70s;
  <br>
  Mozilla firefox: -moz-transition: 0.70s;
  <br>
  Internet Explorer: -ms-transition: 0.70s;
  <br>
  Opera: -o-transition: 0.70s;</h2>
  <h2>More pens coming soon</h2>
```

demo: https://codepen.io/ImageHoverEffects/pen/GfJLg

Answer (score 3):

In your CSS code for the social wrapper class you only needed a period in front of the .social-wrapper:hover to clarify it's modifying the class social-wrapper.

This worked for me:

```
.social-wrapper {
  border-radius:50%; 
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .8s ease-in-out; 
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform .8s ease-in-out; 
  transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
  display: inline;
}

.social-wrapper:hover {
  transform:rotate(360deg); 
  -ms-transform:rotate(360deg); 
  -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg); 
}
```

However, if you may want to have the individual links rotate you'd need to modify your code a little as well. Because you have all the  tags wrapped in the .social-wrapper class it will rotate the whole section of icons. To fix that you'd need to only wrap each individual icon in the .social-wrapper class.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="footer">
    <div id="footer-header">
        <p>Keep Up With Us...</p>
    </div>
    <center><div class="social-wrapper">
        <div id="facebook"><a href="http://www.facebook.com"><img src="Facebook.png" alt="Facebook"></a></div>
        <div id="instagram"><a href="http://www.instagram.com/"><img src="Instagram.png" alt="Instagram"></a></div>
        <div id="twitter"><a href="http://www.twitter.com/"><img src="Twitter.png" alt="Twitter"></a></div>
        <div id="youtube"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/"><img src="Youtube.png" alt="Youtube"></a></div>
    </div></center>
    <div id="tag-branding">
        <img src="tag.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.footer {padding: 376px 0px 0px 0px;}
#footer-header {text-align: center; font-family: 'Raleway'; font-weight: 500; font-size: 29px; line-height: 0; margin: 0;}
#facebook {display: inline; margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;}
#instagram {display: inline; margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;}
#twitter {display: inline; margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;}
#youtube {display: inline; margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;}

.social-wrapper img {border-radius:50%; -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .8s ease-in-out; -ms-transition: -ms-transform .8s ease-in-out; transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;} 

.social-wrapper img:hover {transform:rotate(360deg); -ms-transform:rotate(360deg); -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);}
```

Try above css code now its working fine.

For demo you can check out this : You can use CSS3 transitions to spin the image on hover.

Rotating image :

DEMO

```
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .8s ease-in-out;
          transition:         transform .8s ease-in-out;
}
img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
          transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```