# In place rotate a div with CSS hover

Tags: html, css, sass, css-animations

I would like to rotate the .profile__photo--border-2 div but it keeps on translating. And it doesn't rotate at all.

Here is the code.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

[JSfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/randrini/dmcmysca/5/)

```
  &__photo {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;

    &--border-1, 
    &--border-2 {

      position: absolute;
      height: 110px;
      width: 110px;

      top: 48%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      cursor: pointer;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border-width: 1px;
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: rgb(37, 184, 184) rgb(37, 184, 184) rgb(37, 184, 184) transparent;
      transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;

    }

    &--border-2 {
      height: 120px;
      width: 120px;
      border-color:rgb(37, 184, 184) transparent rgb(37, 184, 184) rgb(37, 184, 184);
    }


    &--border-2:hover {
      /* Something wrong going on here */
      width: 120px;
      height: 120px;
      transform-origin: 0 0;
      transform: rotateZ(360deg);
    }
    & img {
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      z-index: 3;
    }
  }
```

There.

Comment: can you provide some code snippet so we can be able to help you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it within the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spin or rotate an image on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695090/spin-or-rotate-an-image-on-hover)

Comment: There is a jsfiddle link above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were missing some things.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lpavdvko/

```
&--border-1, 
&--border-2 {

  position: absolute;
  height: 110px;
  width: 110px;

  top: 48%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0); <---- new rotate
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(37, 184, 184) rgb(37, 184, 184) rgb(37, 184, 184) transparent;
  transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;

}

&--border-2:hover {
  /* Something wrong going on here */
  transform-origin: 50% 50%; <---- guessing you want to rotate in the center
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg) ; <------ needed to maintain translation
}
```

Comment: Thank your for your time and your help. This solved it. Damn that transform-origin property.

Comment: @r_andrini when in doubt, just apply everything, even if it seems redundant.