# Spin on hover stops anchor from working CSS3/HTML5

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to make an image spin on hover, and link to another page when clicked on a wordpress website. I can get both the spin and anchor working individually, but the anchor wont work when the spin on hover is active. Also for some reason the anchor only works when I have the image as a button. Here's my HTML/CSS:

```
<button class="clear-btn">
<a href="THE LINK"><img src="THE IMAGE" alt="" width="179" height="300" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-14307" />
</a></button>
```

CSS:

```
.hover-spin:hover {
    -webkit-animation:spin 1.5s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 1.5s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 1.5s linear infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); 
transform:rotate(360deg); } }


.clear-btn {
    background: none;
}

.clear-btn:hover {
    background: none;
}
```

Comment: Please refer to this [Spin or rotate an image on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695090/spin-or-rotate-an-image-on-hover)

Comment: I'm not having trouble making the spin effect work, only getting the anchor to work while using the spin effect