# How can I achieve animated zoom on hover using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a project and could use some assistance. I'm aiming to integrate a particular animation effect where, upon hovering over any of the four image selections in the project, I want them to dynamically zoom in and change angles, enhancing the visual experience. I'm hoping to achieve an effect similar to the example I provided. I've checked YouTube and Google, but can't find a guide or video on how to do it, Any guidance on implementing this would be greatly appreciated!

Example:
[zoomed in image when hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86fbP.gif)

here is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello, World!</title>
  </head>
  <style>
body {
  background-color: #eb3477;
}

.sel-btns {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.box {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  border: solid;
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
  width: 65px;
  align-items: flex-end;
  border-radius: .5em;
  background: #d94c74;
}

img {
  position: relative;
  right: 45px;
  top: 5px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
  </style>
  <body>
    <div class='wrapper'>
      <div class="sel-btns">
        <div class="box">
          <a href="#"><img src='https://svgshare.com/i/13sL.svg' title='ice cream' /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          <a href="#"><img src='https://svgshare.com/i/13sL.svg' title='ice cream' /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          <a href="#"><img src='https://svgshare.com/i/13sL.svg' title='ice cream' /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          <a href="#"><img src='https://svgshare.com/i/13sL.svg' title='ice cream' /></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

you can also run the code here!:
https://jsfiddle.net/sofie_anne13/qt3Lvxn8/105/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spin or rotate an image on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695090/spin-or-rotate-an-image-on-hover)

Comment: What , specifically are you having trouble with? Selecting the element on hover? Scaling the zoom? Applying the rotation? Your code doesn't really show any attempt at solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read more about CSS 2D transform [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp) and also CSS hover selector [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.php).

The idea is when your mouse is hover on the ice-cream, you want to rotate and scale it bigger.

```css
body {
  background-color: #eb3477;
}

.sel-btns {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: flex-end;
  overflow: hidden; /* Add this line */
}

.box {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  border: solid;
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
  width: 65px;
  align-items: flex-end;
  border-radius: .5em;
  background: #d94c74;
}

img {
  position: relative;
  right: 45px;
  top: 5px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}


/* Add these */

.ice-cream {
  transition: all .5s;
}

.ice-cream:hover {
  transform: rotate(12deg) translateX(5px) scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class='wrapper'>
    <div class="sel-btns">
      <div class="box">
        <a href="#"><img src='https://svgshare.com/i/13sL.svg' title='ice cream' class='ice-cream' /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <a href="#"><img src='https://svgshare.com/i/13sL.svg' title='ice cream' class='ice-cream' /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <a href="#"><img src='https://svgshare.com/i/13sL.svg' title='ice cream' class='ice-cream' /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <a href="#"><img src='https://svgshare.com/i/13sL.svg' title='ice cream' class='ice-cream' /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```